# Backend service port ignored in traefik on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, kubernetes-helm

I run an app on K8s with a port mapping `30060:30600` with type `LoadBalancer`

Now I want to add traefik to my cluster as reverse proxy with following Ingress setup

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ template "myapp.fullname" . }}-ingress
  labels:
    # deployment labels
    app: {{ template "myapp.name" . }} # app name 
    chart: {{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version | replace "+" "_" }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name | quote }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service | quote }}
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myapp.mybox.internal
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /myapp
        backend:
          serviceName: {{ template "myapp.fullname" . }} # service name 
          servicePort: 30060
```

My issue now is, that the port 30060 is ignored here.

```
==> v1beta1/Ingress
NAME           HOSTS                      ADDRESS  PORTS  AGE
myapp-ingress  myapp.mybox.internal       80       0s
```

The result is, that all requests fail.

If I change the service config from

```
    - targetPort: myapp-port 
      port: 30060
      nodePort: 30060
```

to

```
    - targetPort: myapp-port 
      port: 80
      nodePort: 30060
```

the service is reachable, but:

- App is not reachable under "/myapp"
- but App is reachable under "/" - and I have no idea why?!

So my questions are:
- Why is it not possible to change the service port?
- Why the application does not answer on the mapped path, but on the root path?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your requests are going though Traefik and not just directly via a service proxy?

Comment: @coderanger I changed my traefik port from 80 to 81 and now I get on 80 no answer anymore. So I guess it goes through traffic. I used this as base: https://success.docker.com/article/how-to-configure-traefik-as-a-layer-7-ingress-controller-for-kubernetes

Comment: I can also see in the dashboard, that with 30060 the backend is in state red. With port 80 it appears.